# How to make KotlinX access parent activity's synthetic properties directly?

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in my app. The way I've written is that I have a MainActivity with the layout as provided by the library viz. something like this:

```
<SlidingPanel>
    <MainContentLayout>
    <SlidingPanelContentLayout>
</SlidingPanel>
```

The MainContentLayout is basically a FrameLayout where I load a fragment into. Now here's where it gets tricky--the fragment has code that accesses the slidingupPanel's layout components. When I type the component in Android Studio it automatically imports the correct synthetic property class file as `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_sliding_panel.*` and even autocomplete works to show the correct fields as properties. However, when I run the app is crashes saying that field is a null. To fix this, I have to add `(activity as MainActivity).` as a prefix to all the fields. And when I run this, it fixes the issue.

Is there a cleaner way to do this because writing (activity as MainActivity). in so many locations seems annoying. Is there like a kotlin directive for this and why doesn't KotlinX view binding library auto-detect that the sliding panel layout is on a different layout and therefore write to correct convenience class to access this properly without crashing the app?

Comment: what does ViewBinding have to do with Kotlin synthetics? view binding is a different thing. Are you sure this question is about view binding?

Comment: "Kotlin Synthetics"? I just read their docs and used the terminology they used. They called this feature as View binding in their docs >> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: Yeah, Its actually called Kotlin synthetics in the development world... The Android team also just released a view binding lib which is a part of the Gradle plugin so it will be confusing to say synthetics ViewBinding.

Comment: Ok. Interesting, they should probably mention the right name in their documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to avoid developers from being confused.

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question like this: you are trying to access one of activity's views from fragment it hosts.

Such approach is not good as it couples activity and fragment (thus making fragment non reusable in other activities). If really needed, interaction between activity and fragment can be done using interface activity implements. However you need to keep in mind fragment's lifecycle (in other words activity reference is not always accessible inside fragment). Last but not least, nothing wrong with kotlin extensions.